# Raising an event from usercontrol and notifying subscribers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events, user-controls

I have a usercontrol `DmsRegisterPod` which is being output within a repeater which is itself, inside an `UpdatePanel`. I have an event on the `DmsRegisterPod` called `OnUpdated` which I'm subscribing to in the repeaters `ItemDataBound` event e.g:

```
protected void rptPendingDmsRequests_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DealershipIRLink irLink = (DealershipIRLink)e.Item.DataItem;
        DmsRegisterPod dmsRegisterPod = (DmsRegisterPod)e.Item.FindControl("ucDmsRegisterPod");
        dmsRegisterPod.ValidationGroup = string.Format("dms-pod-{0}", e.Item.ItemIndex);
        dmsRegisterPod.DealershipIRLink = irLink;
        dmsRegisterPod.OnUpdated += dmsRegisterPod_OnUpdated;
    }
}

private void dmsRegisterPod_OnUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DataBind();
}
```

The event is setup as such in the usercontrol:

```
public event EventHandler OnUpdated;

private void Updated(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.OnUpdated != null)
    {
        OnUpdated(this, e);
    }
}
```

It's being raised in the `Accept` click handler:

```
protected void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        this.DealershipIRLink.dms_account_number = txtDmsNumber.Text;

        this.DealershipIRLink.id_dealer_ir_link_status = DealerIRLinkStatus.DealerIRLinkStatusIdentifier.Approved;

        this._irLinkService.UpdateDealershipIRLink(this.DealershipIRLink);

        this.Updated(e);
    }
}
```

However, the handler, `OnUpdated` is always `null` so the event never gets raised. It's as though the control is losing the event binding somehow. Can anybody see what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the event handler in `ItemCreated` instead of `ItemDataBound` which is triggered only when you databind the control and not on every postback(required):

```
protected void rptPendingDmsRequests_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DmsRegisterPod dmsRegisterPod = (DmsRegisterPod)e.Item.FindControl("ucDmsRegisterPod");
        dmsRegisterPod.OnUpdated += dmsRegisterPod_OnUpdated;
    }
}
```

All other logic that depends on the datasource belongs to `ItemDataBound`:

```
protected void rptPendingDmsRequests_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DealershipIRLink irLink = (DealershipIRLink)e.Item.DataItem;
        DmsRegisterPod dmsRegisterPod = (DmsRegisterPod)e.Item.FindControl("ucDmsRegisterPod");
        dmsRegisterPod.ValidationGroup = string.Format("dms-pod-{0}", e.Item.ItemIndex);
        dmsRegisterPod.DealershipIRLink = irLink;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the trick, thanks very much. Out of curiosity, what was happening to the event binding? Was it being lost during postback?

Comment: @DGibbs: **all objects** are disposed at the end of a page's lifecycle and must be recreated on every postback. That happens automatically  on control values like a `TextBox.Text` due to `ViewState` or event-handlers that are added declaratively, but all other objects must be recreated manually.

Comment: Would I need to re-apply the validation group/`DealershipIRLink` in the `ItemCreated` handler too? Currently i'm storing the dataitem id in a hiddenfield and then fetching from the database in the `Accept` but would be nice not to have to do this. I'm guessing this isn't possible due to the `DataSource` obviously not being set.

Comment: @DGibbs: have you tested it? I'm fairly sure that this proeprty is persisted in ViewState or even ControlState. According to your second question: if you need the complete object, i'd load it from database anyway. That would also help to prevent concurrency issues if that object is modified meanwhile.

Comment: I tested it and it was null, so have left the implementation as is since the whole object is needed

Comment: @DGibbs: the `DataItem` is alwayws `null` on postback if you don't load the `DataSource`. I was referring to the `ValidationGroup`.